# SQL. Поиск максимума

Tags: sql, join

Возможно ли вывести название продукта, которое чаще всего встречается в списке при объединении данных?

Есть 2 таблицы:

1. сustomers (ID, Name)
2. products (ID, Cost)
3. orders (CustomerID, ProductID) то есть в этой таблице только 2 ссылки на таблицу клиентов и таблицу продуктов

Пример:

*customers: `[{ID: 12, Name: Vika}, {Id: 23, Name: Alex}]`

*products: `[{ID: 1, Cost: 10}, {ID: 2, Cost: 20}]`

*orders: `[{CustomerID: 12, ProductID: 1}, {CustomerID: 23, ProductID: 2}, {CustomerID: 23, ProductID: 2}]`

Нужно вывести название продукта с ID=2, т.к. его большее кол-во

В таблице orders я посчитала количество каждого товара. А теперь хочу вывести наименование товара, который(-ые) встречается чаще всего. Просто отсортировать и вывести первый товар не могу, т.к. может быть несколько товаров с одинаковым кол-вом. Как быть? Это возможно сделать? 
мой код по подсчету:

```
SELECT products.Title, count(Title) as kol FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.ID = orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN products ON products.ID = orders.ProductID
GROUP BY products.Title
```

Comment: Какая СУБД? включая версию...

Answer (score 0):

Подсчитаем максимальное количество из таблицы orders:

```
SELECT ProductID, MAX(mycount) from (
select ProductID, count() as mycount from orders group by ProductID
) group by ProductID
```

Теперь к полученному результату можем присоединять title продукта